# How do I set a flag on when a ListItem in a ListView is checked and set it off when it is unchecked?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a ListView adapter where I am writing the ListItems from an XML. I want to flag when an item is checked and unflag it when an item is unchecked. I am using an array for storing the flag values. For Example if my ListView has four list items "Red, Blue, Green, Yellow". If Red and Green are checked, the array should be updated to [1, 0, 1, 0] and if they are unchecked it should be updated to [0, 0, 0, 0]. Below is my code. I did something wrong and it is not displaying the desired output. Can someone look into it and suggest me a better way to solve it. Thank you!

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    array =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.facilities);
    strings1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array));

    TopicSelectionListAdapter topicSelectionListAdapter = new TopicSelectionListAdapter(
            second.this, R.layout.listrow, strings1);
    listView.setAdapter(topicSelectionListAdapter);
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    for(int i=0;i<strings1.size();i++){
        listView.setItemChecked(i, false);
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            CheckedTextView selectedItem = (CheckedTextView) view;
            boolean isChecked = selectedItem.isChecked();

            Log.e("TAG","item clicked position = " + position + " isChecked = " + isChecked);
            for(int i=0; i< strings1.size(); i++){
                if(!isChecked){
                    bArray[i]= 0;
                }
                else{
                    bArray[i]= 1;
                }


            }
            for(int i =0; i < bArray.length; i++){
                Log.e("TAG","boolean Array value = " + bArray[i]);
            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this part simply ticks each part of your `bArray`

```
  for(int i=0; i< strings1.size(); i++){
      if(!isChecked){
          bArray[i]= 0;
      }
      else{
         bArray[i]= 1;
      }
  }
```

the reason for this is, you simply wiping your whole array without checking if the element of `bArray` for this particular event checked or not...
doing this should result something better:

```
bArray[position] = isChecked?1:0;
```

Comment: Thank you!! I figured out the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly where your problem is as I'm not sure what output you aren't getting that you think you should and I don't see where `bArray` is declared. But I would probably use a `LinkedHashMap` in this situation. This preserves the order of the `Map` and you can match that position up with the position in your list or compare by names. When that position is checked or unchecked then you can set its value to 1 or 0 accordingly.

**[Here is the Docs on Liked Hashmaps](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)**

Comment: Thanks for your response! I declared my array in the top as ***int[] bArray = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };*** When I select one item, the whole array is set to 1's and if I uncheck one item then the whole array is set to 0's. 

Can you please explain how to LinkedHashMap in this scenario with a small example. It will be greatly appreciated.